# Using hyphen/dash in python repository name and package name

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, package, pypi

I am trying to make my git repository pip-installable. In preparation for that I am restructuring the repo to follow the right conventions. My understanding from looking at other repositories is that I should put all my source code in a package that has the same name as the repository name. E.g. if my repository is called `myrepo`, then the source code would all go into a package also called `myrepo`.

My repository has a hyphen in it for readability: e.g. `my-repo`. So if I wanted to make a package for it with the same name, it would have a hyphen in it as well. [In this tutorial](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html) it says "don't use hyphens" for python package names. However I've seen well-established packages such as `scikit-learn` that have hyphens in their name. One thing that I have noticed though is that in the `scikit-learn` repo, the package name is not the same as the repo name and is instead called `sklearn`.

I think my discussion above boils down to the following questions:

1. When packaging a repo, what is the relationship between the repository's name and the package's name? Is there anything to beware of when having names that don't match?
2. Is it okay to have hyphens in package names? What about in repository names?
3. If the package name for `scikit-learn` is `sklearn`, then how come when I install it I do `pip install scikit-learn` instead of `pip install sklearn`?

Comment: It's the style rule of python to not use hyphens, it is the [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: yes, and it appears that in `scikit-learn` they use `sklearn` as the package name. I don't understand why in pypi it's referred to as `scikit-learn` though: https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/

Comment: No idea why the allowed it but apperantly in the name on pypi.org the hyphens don't matter

Answer (score 81, accepted):

To answer your 1st point let me rephrase [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223150/7976758) to a different question.

The biggest source of misunderstanding is that the word "package" is heavily overloaded. There are 4 different names in the game — the name of the repository, the name of the directory being used for development (the one that contains `setup.py`), the name of the directory containing `__init__.py` and other importable modules, the name of distribution at PyPI. Quite often these 4 are the same or similar but that's not required.

The names of the repository and development directory can be any, their names don't play any role. Of course it's convenient to name them properly but that's only convenience.

The name of the directory with Python files name the package to be imported. Once the package is named for import the name usually stuck and cannot be changed.

The name of the distribution gives one a page at PyPI and the name of distribution files (source distribution, eggs, wheels). It's the name one puts in `setup(name='distribution')` call.

Let me show detailed real example. I've been maintaining a templating library called [CheetahTemplate](http://cheetahtemplate.org/). I develop it in the development directory called `cheetah3/`. The distribution at PyPI is called [Cheetah3](https://pypi.org/project/Cheetah3/); this is the name I put into [`setup(name='Cheetah3')`](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/blob/bf0682b6a8e421c10583ff13f250a5fe973e50ef/SetupConfig.py#L12). The top-level module is [`Cheetah`](https://github.com/CheetahTemplate3/cheetah3/tree/master/Cheetah) hence one does `import Cheetah.Template` or `from Cheetah import Template`; that means that I have a directory `cheetah3/Cheetah/`.

The answer to 2 is: you can have dashes in repository names and PyPI distribution names but not in package (directories with `__init__.py` files) names and module (`.py` files) names because you cannot write in Python `import xy-zzy`, that would be subtraction and `SyntaxError`.

Point 3: The site and the repository names are `scikit-learn`, as well as the [distribution name](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9f0b959a8c9195d1b6e203f08b698e052b426ca9/setup.py#L24), but the importable package (the top-level directory with `__init__.py`) is [sklearn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/tree/master/sklearn).

PEP 8 has nothing to do with the question as it doesn't talk about distribution, only about importable packages and modules.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful!