# PyPI - package contains no files

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I have followed this [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) to upload a package to PyPI. My package is now uploaded to test instance of the index: https://test.pypi.org/project/ilya-ezplots/#files. However when I install it with pip, I still can't import it.

```
>>> import ilya_ezplots
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ilya_ezplots'
```

I have inspected the site-packages of my python interpreter, and found only `ilya_ezplots-0.0.2.dist-info` directory. For other packages there would be two directories, e.g. `h5py-2.9.0.dist-info` and `h5py`.

My setup.py:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="ilya_ezplots",
    version="0.0.2",
    packages=['plots'],
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

Upload script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

rm -r dist
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
python -m twine upload -r testpypi dist/* -u ikamensh
```

File structure:

```
./
./plots/__init__.py
./setup.py
./upload.sh
```

Comment: I have the same issue...

Comment: I think you should create `./ilya_ezplots/__init__.py` not `./plots/__init__.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's me point you to my previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758

`ilya_ezplots` is the name of your distribution but it's not importable name. The importable name after installation is `plots`. So:

```
import plots
```

Comment: I have followed your advice and renamed the directory to have ilya_ezplots/ilya_ezplots/__init__.py, but only __init__.py and no further files are in the PyPI version of my package. Any ideas?

Comment: It was not my advice. I answered your question about import. If you have a new question with a new directory structure it'd be better to ask a new question, show the directory structure and the content of `setup.py`.

Answer (score 0):

As @phd answered, you should import: `import plots`.

or you should change you directory structure to:

`./ilya_ezplots/__init__.py`

And then `import ilya_ezplots` can do the trick.

The name of the import should match the parent directory.

Refer [this](https://gist.github.com/gboeing/dcfaf5e13fad16fc500717a3a324ec17) post to maintain the correct structure and for good practices.

The good practice is maintain some namespace or same directory name as your package name, so that the user won't get confused.

if your project name is `xyz` then you should maintain your directory name as `xyz`. So, the use can do `import xyz` to import your package and won't get confused with the other package. For eg. if you use `yyy` as your directory name (and your package name is `xyz`) then users might get confused and install package `yyy` instead.

One real life example:

package beautifulsoup needs `import bs4` to import it and hence they maintain [`bs4`](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/) package (dummy package) so that no one can create the package with the name `bs4` as that might become a security risk.