# How do I import a local .whl file to Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-wheel

I am trying to use Christoph Gohlke's PyMVPA package (https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pymvpa) in a Jupyter notebook. I've downloaded the correct version (windowsx64 for python 3.7) which I have saved locally as a .whl file.

What's worked so far: I successfully installed pymvpa2 and its related requirements with pip. Pip freeze shows the expected list of packages.

```
pip freeze
    nibabel==2.5.0
    numpy==1.17.0
    pymvpa2==2.6.5
    scipy==1.3.1
    six==1.12.0
```

Importing the other packages (numpy, etc.) to Jupyter also went smoothly.

What hasn't worked: importing pymvpa2.
Bear with me here please, I'm very new at this. Here are some variations I've tried:

```
import mvpa2

import pymvpa2
from pymvpa2 import mvpa2

from users.finnley.downloads.pymvpa import *

from 'users.finnley.downloads.pymvpa' import pymvpa2

from 'users.finnley.downloads.pymvpa' import 'pymvpa2-2.6.5-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl'

from 'users\finnley\downloads\pymvpa' import *
```

Every single one of the above throws a ModuleNotFoundError.

i.e.
     in 
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'users'

or,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymvpa2'
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `import mvpa2`

Comment: The name of the package, reported by the creator and as seen in pip freeze, etc., is pymvpa2, not mvpa2. I did give this a shot just for good measure, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the **distribution package** is [pymvpa2](https://github.com/PyMVPA/PyMVPA/blob/655080971f18c89ce0b9615fd7f76a4b62a114ad/setup.py#L183), but the name of the **importable module** is [mvpa2](https://github.com/PyMVPA/PyMVPA/tree/master/mvpa2). So

```
import mvpa2
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758 for deeper explanation of the difference between distribution packages, importable packages/modules, VCS modules, and development directories.

Comment: The previous commenter suggested this as well, it did not work. "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mvpa2'

Comment: That's a different question. You probably have installed the package into one Python but is trying to import in another. Python package installation is not global — every Python (and every Python virtual environment) has its own list of packages and its own `pip`. So you have to know how many different Pythons you have (including one in Jupyter), and which `pip` installs to which Python.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried to install it in a jupyter terminal that i opened during the same session, which I thought would prevent this problem but maybe not. I used print(sys.prefix) to find the name of the jupyter environment I'm working in. How to I view or change the environment of the terminal?

Comment: The most important info is in `print(sys.path)` — it's the path Python uses to find importable modules. `mvpa2` must be somewhere in the path to be importable. I don't know Jupyter — I don't use it.