# create package with import name different from package name

Tags: python, import, pip, package

The name of the package I want to create is already taken on PyPI. How can I just change the name of the package to upload it on PyPI but keep the original name for imports?

For example, say I'd like to name my package *foo*. Since *foo* is already taken on PyPI, I call my package *foo34* and upload it. How can I make sure that once installed, *foo34* can be imported with a simple *import foo*? (Ignoring the problems it might cause with another package named *foo*)

Additionally, how do I make it work with sphinx (documentation)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758

Comment: Just change the name of the distribution in `setup.py` and regenerate distributions.