# Importing local packages in python

Tags: python, module, pip

Python: 3.10.4
Windows: 10

Ok so I have been struggling with this for while now.

I've been testing module imports in python. I'm using https://github.com/tomchen/example_pypi_package as a (very useful) example. I run the following:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/tomchen/example_pypi_package
cd example_pypi_package
python -m setup.py develop
pip install -e .
```

Now, I expect to be able to import `example_pypi_package` in the REPL of that environment.

```py
import example_pypi_package.module1
```

Yet I get `ModuleNotFoundError`.

How? I checked that my `sys.path` is correct and in my `Lib\site-packages` there is an `example_pypi_package.egg-info` file. I checked that my `sys.execuatble` is the correct environment and installed it with `pip` within that environment. The package shows up in `pip list`. What am I missing? I can't import the package not even import subpackages of that package.

Comment: Are you sure you need `.module1`?  Try it with just `import example_pypi_package`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importable package (directory with `__init__.py`) for this distribution package is `examplepy`. See https://github.com/tomchen/example_pypi_package/tree/main/src/examplepy

So try `import examplepy` or

```
import examplepy.module1
```

PS. The name of a distribution/package/repository could be completely different from importable names. See my examples at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758

Comment: Thank you so much I don't have enough reputation to upvote you but this worked for me.