# How to fix "No module named..." error in Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am getting the following error :

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'create_alias' from module 'src.create_alias'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'helpers'
```

Project Structure looks like

```
project-1
|
|---src
 |---create_alias
   |---__init__.py
   |---create_alias.py
         |---helpers
              |---__init__.py
              |---helper.py
 |---shared_lib
      |
      |---__init__.py
      |---common_helper.py
      |
|--__init__.py
```

project-1 is the project directory and contains the following files/folder

```
README.md       docs            samconfig.toml  template.yml
__init__.py     pyproject.toml  src             venv
```

I have added the following extensions in conf.py

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../project-1'))

extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.viewcode',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.ifconfig',
    'sphinx.ext.githubpages',
    'sphinxcontrib.confluencebuilder'
]
```

Sphinx version : v6.1.2

Comment: Python packages cannot have `-` in their names. Replace it with `_`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/2214933

Comment: Did you use a relative import somewhere in your code?

Comment: "project-1" is the only name that contains a hyphen. Is it really the name of a package?

Comment: @mzjn project-1 is the project directory. I will update the question to include this detail.

Comment: Since there is an `__init__.py` file in the project-1 directory, that makes it look like it is intended as the toplevel package. If that is the case, then Steve Piercy's comment is valid.