# gitlab published package import error: from python_proj_lib import app ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_proj_lib'

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-ci, setup.py, pyproject.toml

I have a project set up with the below structure:

```
python-proj-lib
├──  python_proj_lib
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── constants.py
│       ├── data_types.py
│       ├── app.py
├── README.md
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
|-- .gitlab-ci.yml
└── tests
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_app.py
```

Gitlab packages this just fine and publishes to the package registry, and I am able to install it just fine(`pip install python-proj-lib`). But when I actually try to import the app module as '`from python_proj_lib import app`', it complains package import error: `from python_proj_lib import app ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_proj_lib'`

I think its got to do with the directory name having '-' and package name with '_', but there is a reason I had to have it like this. refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368

### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
name='python_proj_lib',
version="0.1.1",
description='A Python package sample',
url='',
author='xxxxxx xxxxxx',
author_email='redacted',
license='',
packages=find_packages(exclude=\['tests'\]),
install_requires=\['beautifulsoup4==4.12.2',
 ...
'urllib3==2.0.4'
\],

    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: {}'.format("0.1.1"),
        'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
        'Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11',
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.11.4'
)
```

### pyproject.toml

```
[project]
name = "python_proj_lib"
version = "0.1.1"
description = "A python library sample"
license = {text = ""}
authors = [
    {name = "xxxxxx xxxxx", email = "redacted"},
]
dependencies = [
    'beautifulsoup4==4.12.2',
      ...
    'urllib3==2.0.4',
]
requires-python = ">=3.11.4"
```

### .gitlab-ci.yml

```
    stages:
      - build and deploy
      - test
    
    .template_job:
      image: python:3.11.4
      before_script:
        - python3.11 --version
        - pip3 install --upgrade pip
        - python3.11 -m venv venv
        - source venv/bin/activate
    
    build and publish pip pkg:
      extends: ['.template_job']
      stage: build and deploy
      script:
        - pip3 install twine wheel
        - python3.11 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
        - TWINE_USERNAME=gitlab-ci-token TWINE_PASSWORD=${CI_JOB_TOKEN} python3.11 -m twine upload --repository-url ${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/pypi dist/*
      artifacts:
        paths:
          - dist/*.whl
        expire_in: 2 days
    
    test metrics log:
      extends: ['.template_job']
      stage: test
      script:
        - echo "This job tests the initialization and logging of the metrics"
        - python setup.py egg_info
        - pip install -r *.egg-info/requires.txt
        - rm -rf *.egg-info/
        - python -m unittest tests/test_app.py
```

Let me know if you need additional info(intentionally left out lot of detail not relevant to the question), and I can modify the question with additional info/clarification.

I tried renaming the project directory to be the same as the package name (python_proj_lib), but git lab still publishes it as python-proj-lib, and that gives the same error.
My end goal is to be able to package the python app on gitlab, publish it to the private repo, install it from the private repo to my virtual env and be able to import into my program.

Comment: is there a need for setup.py when u already have pyproject.toml. Why not use only poetry.