Python pyproject.toml script import failing
I have the following project layout:

├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── pyproject.toml
├── awesome_package/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __version__.py
    └── main_module.py
    └── some_packages

Inside the awesome_package.main_module there is a function that starts my script (the foo() function).
I'd like to have a some-script script that executes my foo function after installing my library.
This is my pyproject.toml:
[project]
name = "awesome-package"
readme = "README.md"
dynamic = ["version"]
dependencies = [
    ...
]

[project.urls]
...

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = [
    "build"
]

[build-system]
requires = ["hatchling"]
build-backend = "hatchling.build"

[project.scripts]
some-script = "awesome_package.main_module:foo"

[tool.hatch.version]
path = "awesome_package/__version__.py"

[tool.hatch.build.targets.wheel]
packages = ["sphinxlint"]

Using this pyproject.toml I'm able to build the library using:
python -m build

Or for dev purposes
pip install -e '.[dev]'

Everything is working as intended, except for the script which fails to execute. After installation of the wheel, or after the pip install in dev mode, I'm able to run the script some-script. However, it fails to import the foo function and I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Some/path/project_name/venv/bin/some-script", line 7, in <module>
    from awesome_package.main_module import foo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awesome_package'

Any suggestions?
Update
It looks like a problem related to hatchling building backend. Replacing hatchling with setuptools it is working as intended.
This is the updated pyproject.toml:
[project]
name = "awesome-package"
readme = "README.md"
dynamic = ["version"]
dependencies = [
    ...
]

[project.urls]
...

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = [
    "build"
]

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project.scripts]
some-script = "awesome_package.main_module:foo"

[tool.setuptools.dynamic]
version = {attr = "awesome_package.__version__.__version__"}


Is there any particular reason that name = "some-name" (an invalid package name, but that's by the by) doesn't match 'awesome_package' in the example above? The package would be accessible only through some_name, not the name of the directory

Names were not the same, I changed them, but I'm still getting the same error. Now project name and main package name are the same (only different is that the name is awesome-package, while the package is awesome_package

I'm going to update the question, so that at least names are consistent as @roganjosh suggested

@roganjosh [project]name is the name of the distribution so that [project]name = "some-name" produces some-name-$version.whl. awesome_package is the name of importable Python package (a directory with __init__.py and other modules and subpackages). They could be completely different. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758

I'm simply normalizing the name, as here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/name-normalization/#name-format

Anyway, the whl produced name is awesome_package-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl and yes awesome_package is the name of the importable Python package

@phd ugh, I've been working under a misapprehension for a while now. Thanks for that

@phd I'm already lost. "Put the name of your project on PyPI. This field is required and is the only field that cannot be marked as dynamic." - docs. Why on Earth make it a required field when there is absolutely no requirement to distribute on PyPI? I think I'll gracefully back out here and do some more research.

@roganjosh Python build tools always take PyPI (and private indices with the same API) in their minds. PyPI-first approach. :-)
