error: package directory 'mypackage' does not exist using pyproject.toml
Problem
Whilst running some unit tests I was presented with the following error when trying to import from absolute path:
tests/unit/test_parameter_combinations.py:3: in <module>
    from TradingPlatform.core.parameter_combinations import ParameterCombinations
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TradingPlatform'

ChatGPT suggested that if I wanted to package this, it might be useful to create an editable install and this could resolve the path issue.
I also wanted to ship this in the future.
I created the following toml file:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=64", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "TradingPlatform"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "A platform for trading infrastructure and strategy testing."
dependencies = [
    "pandas",
    "numpy",
    "scikit-learn",
    "statsmodels",
]

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["TradingPlatform"]

[tools.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]
include = ["TradingPlatform*"]

This is a simplified project tree (I have removed some of the modules in core and tests to make this smaller).
TradingPlatform
├── __init__.py
├── core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base_trading_strategy.py
├── notebooks
│   └── main.ipynb
├── pyproject.toml
├── tests
│   ├── integration
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── unit
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_strategy_performance_evaluation.py
└── utils
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── helper_funcs.py
    └── logging_setup.py

This has led to the following error error: package directory 'TradingPlatform' does not exist.
What I Have Tried
I have been stuck on this error for quite some time, having tried reconfiguring the toml file, uninstalling and reinstalling the package but to no avail. Below are a few of the different toml file configurations I have tried:
1.
[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["TradingPlatform", "TradingPlatform.core", "TradingPlatform.utils", "TradingPlatform.tests"]

[tool.setuptools.package-dir]
# Explicitly tell setuptools where to find the root package directory
TradingPlatform = "TradingPlatform"




[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["TradingPlatform", "TradingPlatform.core", "TradingPlatform.utils", "TradingPlatform.tests"]




[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["."]

I was expecting to find the directory name, TradingPlatform, and each of the modules
core
tests
utils

in the top_level.txt file within the .egg-info directory, but it is only populated with TradingPlatform and in some instances is empty.
I am quite unfamiliar with shipping a package so would really appreciate any guidance in resolving this issue. Anything else I can provide for further detail, please let me know.

where = ["."] and include = ["TradingPlatform*"] means that TradingPlatform is looked up in ., i.e. in the directory where pyproject.toml resides. There is no TradingPlatform in that directory hence the error. See the tutorial at https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/ See my examples at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758

Thanks very much for pointing this out. It seems I have managed to fix it albeit without fully understanding the process but I'll work through the docs you shared to try and sharpen up.
