# Can a Python package and its corresponding PyPi project have different names?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-packaging

For example, I'm wondering how is it possible that `scikit-learn` is the name of a PyPi package while the actual Python module is named `sklearn`. The reason I'm asking is that I have a local Python package `packageA` that I can't upload to PyPi since that name happens to already be taken. I therefore wonder if I can upload it as `packageB` (which actually is available on PyPi)? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/#configuring-metadata

Comment: Note, using the same import name means these two distributions conflict with each other if somebody installs both.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223150/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The names on PyPi or the names you are useing when doing `pip install NAME` are [Distribution Packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package).

The names you use when doing `import NAME` are [Import Packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Import-Package).

One *Distribution Package* can have multiple *Import Packages* in it.

### Example

As an example see this demo project [bit-demo](https://codeberg.org/buhtz/bit_demo/commit/bb8ec07ae8d4214a5f6ebe8c364df64022dc8e16):

- The name of the repositories (you find in the URL) is "bit-demo".
- The name of the *Distribution Package* (you would use via `pip`) is `bitdemo`. This is [defined in the packages metadata](https://codeberg.org/buhtz/bit_demo/src/commit/bb8ec07ae8d4214a5f6ebe8c364df64022dc8e16/pyproject.toml#L6) via `pyproject.toml` file.
- There are two *Import Packages* in it named `bitcli` and `bitgui`. This is also [defined in the package metadata](https://codeberg.org/buhtz/bit_demo/src/commit/bb8ec07ae8d4214a5f6ebe8c364df64022dc8e16/pyproject.toml#L23-L25).

### Scikit-learn

The project setup of Scikit-learn is bit more complex but you also can see it there.

- The *Distributon Package* name is defined in [`setup.py`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f034f57b1ad7bc5a7a5dd342543cea30c85e74ff/setup.py#L33)
- Not absolute sure about how the *Import Package* name is defined. But I would say `setup.cfg` [tells to look up sub-folders name](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f034f57b1ad7bc5a7a5dd342543cea30c85e74ff/setup.cfg#L5). And there is `scilearn`.