# Fully qualified imports from `foo/setup.py`, `foo/bar/__init__.py` to get `import foo.bar`?

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, python-module, python-packaging

Given this directory structure:

```
/tmp/foo
|-- bar
    `-- __init__.py
`-- setup.py
```

…and this `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = 'foo'
module_name = 'bar'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    packages=find_packages(),
    # Attempts:
    # # `package_dir` omitted entirely
    # package_dir={'': module_name},
    # package_dir={package_name: module_name},
    python_requires=">=3.6",
)
```

But no matter what I do, I can't get `import foo.bar` to work. Some of the attempts get `import foo` to work.

How do I get fully-qualified imports to work?

Comment: In your case `foo` is not a package, it's a directory where `setup.py` resides and nothing more. `bar` is not a module (a file `bar.py` would be a module), it's a package, in your case it's the top-level package. You can import it with `import bar`. If you want to `import foo.bar` you need to make yet another directory `foo` in which you create yet another `__init__.py` and move `bar` into the inner `foo`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54223150/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599368/7976758

Comment: As it is now the your one and only top-level import package is `bar`, so you can `import bar` and nothing else. `bar` is not a module, it is a package.

Comment: According to the most basic [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html) it should be `packages=['bar']`

Comment: Maybe this helps clarifying terms such as "(import) module", "import package", "distribution package": https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/